# Rails3 capistrano, postgresql roles and deploying assets

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3.2, capistrano, asset-pipeline

The context is a trial run to first test the asset deployment in development, before flipping over into production.
uncommenting the line in the following capfile

```
load 'deploy'
    # load 'deploy/assets'
load 'config/deploy'
```

generates a rollback because as the capistrano process is creating the manifest file

```
bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=development RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile && cp -- /Users/stageUser/v4/shared/assets/manifest.yml /Users/stageUser/v4/releases/20140623054425/assets_manifest.yml"
```

it encounters an error

```
 ** [out :: ip] rake aborted!
 ** [out :: ip] FATAL:  role "localhostUser" does not exist
 ** [out :: ip] /Users/stageUser/v4/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1222:in `initialize'
 ** [out :: ip] /Users/stageUser/v4/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1222:in `new'
 ** [out :: ip] /Users/stageUser/v4/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1222:in `connect'
 ** [out :: ip] /Users/stageUser/v4/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/
```

localhostUser is not invoked anywhere on staging server, in deploy.rb nor in Capfile.  It is only defined for development and test database use on localhost.  the error is clearly occuring via postgresql_adapter.rb

**update**  oddity.  The closing error reference states:

```
failed: "rvm_path=$HOME/.rvm/ $HOME/.rvm/bin/rvm-shell '1.9.3@v4'
```

ruby version 1.9.3 ... vs the bundle path for ruby at 1.9.1 ... hmmm.  could that be related?
**end update**

What is the postgresql_adapter being invoked by deploy/assets.  The only clue is the manifests.yml file that could be read as a database initializer...  that line does invoke 'connection_parameters'  But then why is it using localhostUser when the stageServer has no knowledge of it?

database.yml usernames are defined differently between localhost and staging server, but I cannot fathom why this would influence the capfile.

How can I ensure that the role is properly set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What follows is a patch, but not a proper answer to the problem.

It all has to do with postgresql and its roles.  My database.yml file being .gitignore(d) I had different values for username (or 'role' for postgresql)

```
sudo su localhostUser
```

which was not postgre (complicating matters a bit, throwing me into another cluster)

```
createuser stageUser
```

I admit I'm not certain if this is a necessary part of the solution, but WT... playing it safe

Then, in sequence:

```
pg_dump app_development > mydb.sql
rake db:migrate VERSION=0
```

change username in database.yml file from localhostUser to stageUser

```
rake db:migrate
```

edit mydb.sql replacing string of localhostUser to stageUser

```
psql app_development < mydb.sql
```

deploy now runs.

This confirms that the task is NOT using the staging server's database.yml data but some cache of that from the localhost.  **not what I would expect**